# How do i calculate the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How do i prove this relationship?
[image]

EDIT:
I dont have any direction, the minor technique didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will solve this via induction on $n.$ This way we will be able to relate the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix with an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix.

So we start with the Base Case $n=2,$ in this case we have
$$
\begin{align}
\det\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1+x & x\\
x & a_2+x\\
\end{bmatrix}
&=(a_1+x)(a_2+x)-x^2\\
&=a_1a_2+a_1x+a_2x+x^2-x^2\\
&=a_1a_2+x(a_1+a_2).
\end{align}
$$

This proves that the identity holds for the Base Case $n=2.$ Now, for the Inductive Step suppose that the identity holds for some $n=k,$ we will prove it for $n=k+1.$

We will use the classic method of computing the determinant of an $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ matrix using the determinants of $k\times k$ matrices in it.

We have;
$$
\begin{align}
\det\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1+x & x & \cdots & x\\
x & a_2+x & \cdots & x\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x & x & \cdots & a_{k+1}+x\\
\end{bmatrix}
&=(a_1+x)\det\begin{bmatrix} 
a_2+x & x & \cdots & x\\
x & a_3+x & \cdots & x\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x & x & \cdots & a_{k+1}+x\\
\end{bmatrix}+\cdots
\\
\end{align}
$$

If we will expand this using the Induction Hypothesis, then this will prove the claim for $n=k+1,$ and the result will be proved.

(Please do the expanding yourself, I very exhausted to do it, Best of Luck)